# Can I lint files that use boost's ptr_vector.hpp?

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse, embedded, pc-lint

I am just starting on using boost in my embedded environment. I changed a vector to use a ptr_vector and the code compiled and tested fine. I used:

```
#include <boost/ptr_container/ptr_vector.hpp>
```

Then I went to lint the file (with Gimpel's PC Lint) and I get a strange error:

```
#... mpl/aux_/preprocessed/plain/.hpp)
#   include BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(boost/mpl/aux_/preprocessed/AUX778076_PREPROCESSED_HEADER)
LINT Error: C:\SW_DEV\boost_1_51_0\boost\mpl\aux_\include_preprocessed.hpp:37  
322 Unable to open include file 'boost\mpl\aux_\preprocessed\plain\.hpp'
```

The directory exists but there is of course no file named `.hpp`. I'm not sure what BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE or AUX778076_PREPROCESSED_HEADER is, or if I have to do some special installation step. I was mostly planning on working with the pieces that are just .hpp.  I just downloaded boost and put it on my hard drive and then told the Eclipse project where to find the root boost include directory.  (I did tell lint about the root to the boost directory also).

### Edit

I tried linting a file using `#include <boost/scoped_ptr.hpp>` and it worked, so it does look like it is include file specific. I updated the post title to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIR, it is selects file to include from boost\mpl\aux_\preprocessed depending on compiler. So please refer to [Gimpel documentation](http://www.gimpel.com/html/pub90/gcc-readme.txt) how to configure pclint to mimic gcc compiler.